# Get phrases with 3 words

Tags: python, text, words

I have tried to figure this one out for some time now.

I want to take a large text/string and split it into phrases of 3 words, and add them to an array.

I have tried using `spilt()` but it dosen't work as I hoped.

What I was thinking of doinig, to get it to work:

Start with the first 3 words in the string, when I got those, I put it in an array and move 1 word and take the next 3 words and so on and so on.

Is this a bad way of doing this?

Kind regards :)

Comment: There are various NLP packages that provide trigram parsing - `nltk` for example.  Using one of them will save you some effort.  (If you want to actually build a trigram parser yourself, please provide a specific example to work with, including edge cases like how to handle punctuation, numbers, etc, and expected output.)

Comment: Thanks @andrew_reece for your information, about NLTK at some point i am going to change the way i do this, right now im just trying to make the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_really_long_string = "this is a really long string"
split_string = my_really_long_string.split()
phrase_array = [" ".join(split_string[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(split_string) - 2)]
```

The first line just represents your string.

After that, just split on the spaces, assuming that's all you care about for defining the end of words.  (@andrew_reece's comments about edge cases is highly relevant.)

The next one iterates on the range of 0 to n-2 where n is the length of the string.  It takes 3 consecutive words from the split_string array and joins them back with spaces.

This is almost certainly not the fastest way to do things, since it has a split and a join, but it is very straightforward.

```
>>> my_really_long_string = "this is a really long string"
>>> split_string = my_really_long_string.split()
>>> phrases = [" ".join(split_string[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(split_string) - 2)]
>>> 
>>> phrases
['this is a', 'is a really', 'a really long', 'really long string']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks :) that was exactly what i needed. 

Now i just need to strip out all commas, punctuation and more from the tekst, so i only get clean text.

Thanks a lot Scott, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This would work.  You might want to strip the text of characters first, not sure what your data is.

```
x = 'alt bot cot dot eat fat got hot iot jot kot lot mot not'
x = [y for y in [x.strip().split(' ')[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(x), 3)]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input :) I got it working now, now i just need to clean the html i got :) 

Så mange tak for hjælpen :) 
Ved du endelig om der findes nogle danske python forummer på FB?, har kigget men ikke fundet nogle endnu.

Comment: The difference with mine is that it produces a list of lists.